# Like Dialog in facebook android sdk is closed immediately

Tags: facebook-like, facebook-android-sdk

I'm using Facebook Android SDK (3.19) in my app and following this link https://developers.facebook.com/docs/android/like-button to use Like Button. When I clicked like button, Like Dialog was shown and dismissed immediately. Also, onActivityResult was not called. I don't know why. Please somebody help me to fix this. Thanks.

Edit: My code

```
    public class ContentFragment extends Fragment{

    LikeView likeView;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setRetainInstance(true);

        Settings.sdkInitialize(getActivity());
        Settings.setPlatformCompatibilityEnabled(false);
        Settings.setIsDebugEnabled(true);

    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
            Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View view = LayoutInflater.from(getActivity()).inflate(R.layout.content_fragment, null);

        likeView = (LikeView) view.findViewById(R.id.like_view);
        likeView.setObjectId("http://shareitexampleapp.parseapp.com/photo1/");
    }

    @Override
    public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        LikeView.handleOnActivityResult(getActivity(), requestCode, resultCode, data);
        Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "onActivityResult", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
}
```

Edit2: CLOSED. It's my mistake. My test account was not added to my facebook app's testers. Thanks.

Comment: Can you show the code as you have it in your app?

Comment: @EWit, I edited with my code. Thanks